# How do I return only the matching regular expression when I select-string(grep) in PowerShell?

Tags: regex, powershell, grep

I am trying to find a pattern in files. When I get a match using `Select-String` I do not want the entire line, I just want the part that matched.

Is there a parameter I can use to do this?

For example:

If I did

```
select-string .-.-.
```

and the file contained a line with:

```
abc 1-2-3 abc
```

I'd like to get a result of just **1-2-3** instead of the entire line getting returned.

I would like to know the Powershell equivalent of a `grep -o`

Comment: If part of your regexp is used to filter the lines you print, but you don't want to print that part, you can use lookahead and lookbehind groups (same as `grep -ohP`). Suppose you want to get the number in `keep 123 good` but not in `drop 456 nogood` then you can use `(Select-String '(?>=keep )123(?= good)' myfile.txt).Matches.Value`, result: `123`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

David's on the right path.  [regex] is a type accelerator for System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex

```
[regex]$regex = '.-.-.'
$regex.Matches('abc 1-2-3 abc') | foreach-object {$_.Value}
$regex.Matches('abc 1-2-3 abc 4-5-6') | foreach-object {$_.Value}
```

You could wrap that in a function if that is too verbose.

Answer (score 42):

Or just:

```
Select-String .-.-. .\test.txt -All | Select Matches
```

Comment: To add some additional information: `Select[-Object] Matches` outputs _custom objects_ with a `.Matches` property copied from `Select-String`'s `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`-typed output objects. If you want to output the actual _text_ captured by the regex, use `ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Value }` instead, assuming there's only 1 match per line. If there are multiple - which there could be due to `-All[Matches]`, the `grep -o` equivalent - you can use `ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }` in PSv3+; in PSv2 you'd have to enumerate the `$_.Matches` collection explicitly.

Comment: `echo "abcd" | Select-String -Pattern '(ab)' | Select Matches` returns {0}

Comment: Yeah this just returns stuff like `{0, 0, 0, 0, ...}` and not the actual matched values....

Comment: and `ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }` returns one blank line per match...

Answer (score 33):

I tried other approach: Select-String returns property Matches that can be used. To get all the matches, you have to specify -AllMatches. Otherwise it returns only the first one.

My test file content:

```
test test1 alk atest2 asdflkj alj test3 test
test test3 test4
test2
```

The script:

```
select-string -Path c:\temp\select-string1.txt -Pattern 'test\d' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

returns

```
test1 #from line 1
test2 #from line 1
test3 #from line 1
test3 #from line 2
test4 #from line 2
test2 #from line 3
```

[Select-String at technet.microsoft.com](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315403.aspx)

Comment: I couldn't get this one working, i only have access to PS 1.0 and it doesn't look like -AllMatches is recognized in 1.0 at least. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Hmm, I work with v2, ctp3. I have no possibility to try to solve that on v1, so sorry..

Comment: Support for matches was added in v2, in addition to context.

Answer (score 16):

In the spirit of [teach a man to fish](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Chinese_proverbs#Sh) ...

What you want to do is pipe the output of your select-string command into **Get-member**, so you can see what properties the objects have. Once you do that, you'll see "Matches" and you can select just that by piping your output to `| **Select-Object** Matches`.

My suggestion is to use something like: select linenumber, filename, matches

For example: on stej's sample:

```
sls .\test.txt -patt 'test\d' -All |select lineNumber,fileName,matches |ft -auto

LineNumber Filename Matches
---------- -------- -------
         1 test.txt {test1, test2, test3}
         2 test.txt {test3, test4}
         3 test.txt {test2}
```

Answer (score 13):

None of the above answers worked for me. The below did.

```
Get-Content -Path $pathToFile | Select-String -Pattern "'test\d'" | foreach {$_.Matches.Value}

Get-Content -Path $pathToFile | # Get-Content will divide into single lines for us

Select-String -Pattern "'test\d'" | # Define the Regex
```

foreach {$_.Matches.Value} # only return the value of the Object's Matches field. (This allows for multiple result matches.)

Comment: powerShell 7.1 requires `-AllMatches` to be used with `select-string` to return all matches, like `"test1 test2 test3" | Select-String -Pattern "test\d" -AllMatches | foreach {$_.Matches.Value}`. Only first match is returned by `select-string` otherwise

Comment: Working fine without `-All` on PWSH 7.2.2, @oleksa.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of piping to `%` or `select` you can use simpler `.prop` [Member Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#member-enumeration) syntax, which magically works on multiple elements:

```
(Select-String .-.-. .\test.txt -All).Matches.Value
```

or less parentheses:

```
$m = Select-String .-.-. .\test.txt -All
$m.Matches.Value
```

Comment: This saves so much pain and typing!

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use ForEach operator, you can only use pipes and `Select -Expand`

For example, to get only the path after `C:\`, you could use :

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern "(C:\\)(.*)" | Select -Expand Matches | Select -Expand Groups | Where Name -eq 2 | Select -Expand Value
```

`Where Name -eq 2` only selects the second match of the regex pattern specified.

Comment: for picking out the matched string when also using lookahead/lookbehind this is the approach that worked for me. `cat myfile | select-string "(?<=before).+(?=after)" | Select -Expand Matches | Select -ExpandProperty Value`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Comment: That's not a solution for PowerShell though as asked for by the OP, is it?