# Using Select-String to extract all event titles, which are in parentheses, from a txt file

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I'm trying to extract the titles of events in one of my logs, which is just a text file with lots of data. The filename is `eventlog-1-5-2016.txt` (date is always the current date). Each line in the file is one event like this:

```
1-1-16(Commodore Rally)Address|Time
1-2-16(Open House)Address|Time
```

I just want to go through the file and extract the title in parentheses, excluding the parentheses themselves, and output the list to the console, or a text file.

I've also tried output to a txt file but I'm missing something.  Can you tell me why this doesn't work:

Console:

```
Select-String -Path c:\log\eventlog-1-5-2016.txt -Pattern '\(([^\)]+)\)' -AllMatches |
  % { $_.Matches }
```

To File:

```
Select-string -Path c:\log\eventlog-1-5-2016.txt -Pattern '\(([^\)]+)\)' -AllMatches |
  % { $_.Matches } | { $_.Value > C:\log\results.txt
```

or even a better way to do this if this wrong.

Bonus question, could the path auto calculate the current date and correct the file name for easy future pasting? (not major!)

Comment: When asking `why this doesn't work`, please explain, in as many detail as possible, what actually happens. The input and desired outputs are  described, so the question is in pretty good shape.

Comment: What is your output and what do you not understand about it?

Comment: Try  changing the pattern to `'(?<=\()[^\)]+)(?=\))'` since you are using `Matches`.

Comment: Thank folks, good point.  There isn't any output at all.  I just get >> on the screen and nothing in the output file.

Comment: Stribizhev - when i use your expression it says - Too many )'s.

Comment: The double greater-than symbols `>>` indicate that PowerShell is expecting more input. That will either be just a <RETURN> (typically if you've pasted several lines of code with parentheses / brackets), or a close parentheses / bracket because you have got the open/close balance wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current date can be determined like this:

```
(Get-Date).ToString('d-M-yyyy')
```

Also, your regular expression could be simplified a little by using a non-greedy match:

```
`\((.+?)\)
```

If you want just the text between the parentheses you need the value of the captured group instead of the complete match:

```
$date = (Get-Date).ToString('d-M-yyyy')
Select-String -Path "C:\log\eventlog-$date.txt" -Pattern '\((.+?)\)' -AllMatches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1] } |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Value } |
  Out-File 'C:\log\results.txt'
```

If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you could collapse the `ForEach-Object` statements:

```
Select-String -Path "C:\log\eventlog-$date.txt" -Pattern '\((.+?)\)' -AllMatches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value } |
  Out-File 'C:\log\results.txt'
```

Or you could use the `-match` operator:

```
Get-Content "C:\log\eventlog-$date.txt" |
  Where-Object { $_ -match '\((.+?)\)' } |
  ForEach-Object { $matches[1] } |
  Set-Content 'C:\log\results.txt'
```

Comment: The example with -match was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that `Select-String` doesn't quite do what you think it does. It will match patterns, but instead of returning the matched part, it will return you the whole matching string. Thus, the statement returns you the whole matched row instead of just substring in parenthesis. This is common a [cause for confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804754/how-do-i-return-only-the-matching-regular-expression-when-i-select-stringgrep).

As a simple example in case of link rot,

```
[regex]$rx = '\(([^\)]+)\)'
cat C:\Temp\logfile.txt | % { $rx.Matches( $_ ).value }
(Commodore Rally)
(Open House)
```

Comment: results were empty running this, though there wasn't an error.  The expression itself must not match.  Maybe that's my problem.

Comment: `Select-String` returns a [`MatchInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo.aspx) object, not just the matching string.