# powershell extract number with regex

Tags: regex, powershell, numbers

I need to extract **only the numbers** from external file. I am using the following command:

```
(Get-Content -Path .\log.html) | Select-String -Pattern 'load is'
```

It then returns:

```
<tr><td>server-67 load is: 0</td></tr>
<tr><td>server-68 load is: 5875</td></tr>
<tr><td>server-69 load is: 6077</td></tr>
<tr><td>server-70 load is: 6072</td></tr>
<tr><td>server-71 load is: 5846</td></tr>
<tr><td>server-72 load is: 1900</td></tr>
<tr><td>server-73 load is: 1900</td></tr>
```

I only need to extract the number portion.
How can I do it?

Comment: You can adapt Keith Hill's solution combined with a [look-behind](http://www.powershellcookbook.com/recipe/qAxK/appendix-b-regular-expression-reference): `(Get-Content -Path .\log.html) | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=load is: )(\d+)' -All | Select Matches`. Although, does "**only the numbers**" include the server numbers?

Comment: @SimonShine: A near-duplicate, for sure, but there's a twist (matching via surrounding in-line context) that makes it a distinct question. Note that `Select Matches` outputs _custom_ objects with a `.Matches` property, which is not the same as outputting just the captured numbers. Also, there is no need for `-All`, unless you want to capture multiple matches _per line_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What distinguishes this question from the near-duplicate at "[How do I return only the matching regular expression when I select-string(grep) in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804754/how-do-i-return-only-the-matching-regular-expression-when-i-select-stringgrep)" is the desire to **extract substrings of interest via *surrounding in-line context not to be included in the match***:

```
PS> Select-String '(?<=load is: )\d+' .\log.html | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Value }
0
5875
6077
6072
5846
1900
1900
```

<sup>If you want to output actual *numbers*, simply place `[int]` (for instance) before `$_.Matches[0].Value` to cast (convert) the text results to an integer.</sup>

- `Select-String` can accept file paths directly, so for a single file or a group of files matched by a wildcard expression you generally don't need to pipe from `Get-Content`.
  (For processing entire directory subtrees, pipe from `Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse`).
- Regex `'(?<=load is: )\d+'` **uses a (positive) [lookbehind assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_positive_lookbehind_assertion) (`(?<=...)`)** to match part of each line without including what was matched in the result; only the `\d+` part - a nonempty run of digits - is captured.
- `Select-String` outputs `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]` instances whose `.Matches` property contains the results of regex matching operation; its `.Value` property contains what the regex captured.

---

In the case at hand, the lookbehind solution is probably simplest, but an **alternative solution is to use a [capture group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions), which is ultimately more flexible**:

```
# Same output as above.
Select-String 'load is: (\d+)' .\log.html | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value}
```

What the capture group (the parenthesized subexpression, `(...)`) matched is available on the output objects' `.Matches.Groups` collection, whose element at index `0` contains the overall match, and element `1` containing the 1st capture groups, `2` the 2nd, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility:

```
(Get-Content -Path .\log.html) |
    Where-Object {$_ -match '^<tr><td>server-(?<Server>\d{1,}) load is: (?<load>\d{1,})</td></tr>$'} |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PsCustomObject]@{"ServerNumber"=$matches.Server;"ServerLoad"=$matches.Load}
        }
```

This will give you output like this:

```
ServerNumber ServerLoad
------------ ----------
67           0         
68           5875      
69           6077      
70           6072      
71           5846      
72           1900      
73           1900
```